# Which is the Design Pattern of Fallback services in an array

Tags: design-patterns, composite, chain-of-responsibility

Let's suppose I've seen a `FallbackCompositeService` that is used by a client object to obtain a result with a fallback mechanism.
It implements a `FallbackServiceInterface` with a method `doSomething()`.

We have a DI container providing the service, which is instantiated with a series of concrete fallback strategies (pseudo-PHP example here):

```
new FallbackCompositeService([
  new Rule1FallbackService(),
  new Rule2FallbackService(),
   ... 
])
```

Every fallback service implements `FallbackServiceInterface` too, so they also `doSomething()`.

When we call `$result = $fallbackCompositeService->doSomething()`, the service cycles through its child services calling the same method, the first non-null Rule response "wins" and is returned.

The question is:

- is this implementation a "degenerate" version of the Composite pattern (hence the name)?
- or is it a "degenerate" version of Chain of Responsibility (where the `nextHandler()` pointer is simplified to an iteration through an array)?
- or something else/undefined/both/whatever...? And its potential drawbacks?

Comment: This isn't a "design pattern" at all (in the GOF sense) because it doesn't concern OOP design.

Comment: @Dai. Disagree, to me it is a pattern, it relies on composition, classes, interfaces organized in a specific and describable way and for a specific purpose. If it is efficient or not, or if it is a degenerate form of a more elegant GoF pattern is imho debatable, and that's precisely what I asked for.

Comment: Sounds more like an automatic Strategy pattern with the unfortunate issue of having to actually try the strategy to know if it's the one you need.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils not unfortunate if fallback logic is what you strive for. Moreover, we are non injecting the specific strategy in this case, so I'm not really convinced.

Comment: True, but necessary things can still be unfortunate. Further, it's not necessary to "inject the specific strategy" for it to be the strategy pattern; how did you come to that understanding?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I though the Client was responsible for choosing the strategy at runtime. Here the client depends on an "aggregator" of strategies.

Comment: That's the classic example but not a necessity. Ultimately, the strategy could be selected ["depending on the type of data, the source of the data, user choice, or other discriminating factors."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, I wouldn't recommend quoting Wikipedia on design patterns. The articles are not written by authoritative sources and can be rife with inaccuracy. Unfortunately, you can't trust many of the highly-upvoted threads on SO either; so the only real source of truth is the book(s) where the patterns were originally published.

Comment: @jaco0646, indeed, it's not my preferred source but my pattern books stay at work. But, unfortunately, books, not matter how great they are when published, suffer from their static nature. Patterns turn to anti-patterns and so forth. Ultimately, I use logic to guide me. There are plenty of examples of strategies being decoupled from the client, similar or same as the fallback they're describing; game attack strategies come to mind or any other "default" strategy pattern with alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Composite Pattern envisages the creation of a tree structure comprising composite and leaf nodes - such as generated by an expression parser for example. All nodes have the same interface and contain their own implementation of evaluate(). When evaluate() is called on the head node, all nodes will contribute their part of the final answer (in the correct order as dictated by the tree traversal - assuming the parser knows what its doing!). This is not the same as your example, where processing stops when one node does its job.

Chain of Responsibility envisages a linked list of objects - each implementing the same Interface eg doSomething(). When doSomething() is called on the head object it either does something and returns OR its doSomething() calls the next objects doSomething() and so on until something is done (or not!). This is a lot more like your example, except in your case you are manually trying each each callback in your injected array until one is successful.

So your example looks a lot like an implementation of the "intent" of the Chain of Responsibility strategy.

Note there is quite a lot of similarity between various patterns and Chain of Responsibility, Decorator, and Composite all use link lists of node objects to do their thing. Their intent is different, but its easy to postulate that any pattern is a degenerate version of any other. A tree (Composite) is a linked list where each node has only one child (Decorator and Chain).

The point was made that patterns usually involve OOP, while your example is phrased in terms of callbacks. So if you denoted in your comments that you were following the Chain pattern, code reviewers may look for a conventional OOP implementations and get confused. But as stated, your code does the job intended, but its not 100% clear to label it Chain pattern without qualifying notes.